# Slash after script name in URL

Tags: php, apache

My own site has one weird bug: I can put anything with slash in the end of URL and it doesn't show 404 error, it working fine. For example:

1. That is normal URL: http://site.com/path/index.php
2. I put "/aaa.php" in the end: http://site.com/path/index.php/aaa.php - and it show me normal URL (like in 1).

What is it? How to remove this behaviour? I want to see 404 error in second case.

Apache/2.2.24 (FreeBSD)
PHP 5.4.10

Comment: That's normal behaviour for PHP. It isn't a bug.

Comment: @Quentin, Thank you for info! Do you know why this behaviour was added in PHP? Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: @Prix — I just disabled Multiviews on my server, and have no Rewrite rules at all. Still works.

Comment: @Quentin AFAIK when the `MultiViews` is enabled it will try to shift your URL to the file its closest to which would produce the above behavior.

Comment: @Quentin, I add

<Directory "/usr/home/site/pub/htdocs/">
 Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

but it doesn't help.

Comment: @BArtWell — I said Multiviews had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Quentin, oh, sorry, that is my mistake.

Comment: @BArtWell if you want to prevent that, there is a way with mod_rewrite, but that will depend if you have any other .htaccess files and rules already in place. Let me know if that interests you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why adding in the url "/something/watever" after a "page.php" doesn't trigger a 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408479/why-adding-in-the-url-something-watever-after-a-page-php-doesnt-trigger-a)

Answer (score -1):

It is default behaviour of (almost) every webserver with serverside scripting (like PHP & others) support. 
You can try it with PHP, in that case check if $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] matches $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], but that works only if you don't use URL rewriting. 
You can also disable MultiViews option, as Prix pointed out.

Comment: There's no `?` in the URL so there isn't a query string.

Comment: @Quentin you know that you can make it so htaccess file converts everything after a file to GET values?

Comment: Ok, you're correct. It doesn't show up in QUERY_STRING. I'll correct my answer.