# How to handle this URL?

Tags: php, url

I have `http://www.example.com/contact-us.php` URL which is working perfectly but if someone put `http://www.example.com/contact-us.php/contact-us.php` it shows the page with CSS disturbed.

Can we show *page not found message* to users for this `http://www.example.com/contact-us.php/contact-us.php` URL? If this page is or is not present.

**Update :**

My .htacess file - /public_html/.htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Seems your site is affected by `.htaccess` settings. Please post its contents as well.

Comment: @Raptor Full page content ?

Comment: contents of `.htaccess`

Comment: @Raptor I dont have .htacess file on server

Comment: Related: [Slash after script name in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804205/slash-after-script-name-in-url)

Comment: Also: [What happens when i put a slash (/) after a .php url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299243/what-happens-when-i-put-a-slash-after-a-php-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an htaccess file on your server and force trailing slash for all URLs that don't point directly to a file like this (do check whether [mod_rewirte is enabled or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    #Force Trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^((.*)[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have put above on my .htacess file but its not working

Comment: @RakeshShetty Please update your question with the complete code of the htaccess file and do mention its file path

Comment: @RakeshShetty You have mis-spelled the htaccess file. It should be ".htaccess". Rename it and check again.

Comment: it was a typo in question but on server it is .htaccess

Comment: @RakeshShetty Please try again with the updated answer after enabling mod_rewrite (if it isn't already enabled)