# Why adding in the url "/something/watever" after a "page.php" doesn't trigger a 404?

Tags: php, apache, url

I have a webpage with url `site.com/index.php`. The strange thing is, that when I add `/something/whatever` (or anything else) to the URL, making it `site.com/index.php/something/whatever`, the `index.php` page is still loading.

I don't get why the server isn't just returning a **404 Not Found error**.

I've tried other site, like `php.net`. You can try to go on https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php/,

Then add after the `/` something, like this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php/test/like/test/fuhzefuizh.

I still don't get why it's showing the `page.php` and not a 404 error (because obviously, folder or URI "fuhzefuizh" doesn't exist).

Comment: Maybe some issue with `mod_rewrite`. This one is often used to redirect all URLs to a single PHP file so you can have dynamic routes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have foud that it's a normal behaviour depending the server configuration. It's the `AcceptPathInfo` rule, we can just turn it off with `AcceptPathInfo off`.